# Disable part of textarea content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have textarea with a static content. So I disabled the textarea to prevent any modification in the content. But I want to modify some part of this content. How can I do this ?

I have created a select box as follows :

```
<div class="scroll-inside">
    <?php if($transactionalTemplates->num_rows() > 0) { 
        foreach($transactionalTemplates->result_array() as $template) { ?>
            <a href="#" class="transactionalTemplate" data-text="<?php echo $template['TemplateText']?>">
                <?php echo $template['TemplateText'];?>
            </a>

    <?php   }
       }
   ?>
</div>
```

When I select an item, the selected item will pasted to the following textarea

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter your message here.." maxlength="160" class="messageTransactional" name="messageTransactional" id="messageTransactionalEnglish"></textarea>
```

here is my script code:

```
$('.transactionalTemplate').click(function() { 
        $('.messageTransactional').val($(this).data('text'));
        flag = true;
        $('.messageTransactional').keypress(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

After adding the content to textarea, I prevent typing new content using the above function. 
here is an example:

Suppose `Dear (123), thanks for registering with us. Please subscribe our new offer to send unlimited SMS. For details please call (123)` is my content.

I need to edit this content as `Dear John, thanks for registering with us. Please subscribe our new offer to send unlimited SMS. For details please call 91xxxxxxxx`

Which means, I need to change the content in paranthesis, keeping the format static.

Comment: So the user should change (123) to 91xxxxxxxx?

Comment: Yes, it is common template for different users

Comment: Why are you using a text area if the content is not editable, couldn't you use a different element like a `pre` if you need monospace,

Comment: @synthet1c all the contents included in `()` are editable

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest not using a textarea. There is no real way to stop that. You would need to do it yourself and try to catch every possibility to change that.

Instead, a simple text-input usually looks the best.

Alternatively, if it has to be seamless, you can use a `contenteditable` span, like this:

```html
Dear <span contenteditable="true">(please enter your name here)</span>, thanks for registering with us. Please subscribe our new offer to send unlimited SMS. For details please call <span contenteditable="true">(please enter your tel. number here)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so did a pretty cool solution, it's not perfect though and still needs work for production.

```js
const $editable = $('.editable')
const $inputs = $('.input')
const $save = $('#save')

const popup = function(e) {
  const $this = $(this)
  $this
    .find('input')
    .addClass('active')
    .focus()
}

const onBlur = function(e) {
  const $this = $(this)
  const $parent = $this.parent()
  const value = $this.val()
  
  $parent.find('input')
    .removeClass('active')
  
  if (value) {
    $parent
      .find('.value')
      .text($this.val())
  }
}

const onSave = function(e) {
  const $pre = $('pre')
  console.log('save', $pre.text())
}

$editable.on('click', popup)
$inputs.on('blur', onBlur)
$save.on('click', onSave)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.editable {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #3cf;
  color: #3cf;
  min-width: 1em;
  min-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.editable input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  transform: translate(-70px, 0%);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .4s opacity ease, .4s transform;
}

.editable input:focus,
.editable input.active {
  transform: translate(-70px, -100%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: none;
}

.editable:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  padding: .5em 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="messageTransactional" />

<pre id=="messageTransactional">
Dear <span class="editable" id="name"><span class="value">name</span><input type="text" class="input" /></span>, thanks for registering with us. Please subscribe our new offer to send unlimited SMS. For details please call <span class="editable" id="phone"><span class="value">phone</span><input type="text" class="input" /></span> is my content.
</pre>

<button id="save" class="button">save</button>
```

Comment: It's pretty cool. but can i use textarea instead of `<pre>` and `<span>` because the actual functionality is either you can create new template and save it or you can select already saved template from drop down and modify it. the structure of the saved template keep as it is if you modify this