# How to implement text area where existing value cannot be changed?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have one Angular application where I want to implement a text area. In that text area, there will be some existing value (can be anything) that cannot be modified or removed. But users can add new values after the existing one and that new value can be modified or removed. 
How can I implement a text area like this? 
Example: 
[image: Example Image]

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to make a `<div>` that contain a textarea with an disabled input inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464697/how-to-have-a-disabled-text-in-textarea-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to search more on here, or on internet.
The bellow page can be useful:

[Disable part of textarea content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284680/disable-part-of-textarea-content)

So, to be found here (use `contenteditable` on a span):

```html
    <div>
      Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. <span contenteditable="true"></span>
    </div>
```

The dummy text will be added with your specific Angular sintex etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component like this and pass the fixed text. Try like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-editor">
  <span id="fixedText">Fixed text</span>
  <textarea style="padding-top:{{ fixedTextHeight }}px" 
  (change)="onValueChange($event)"></textarea>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  fixedTextHeight ;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var el = document.getElementById('fixedText');

    var elHeight =
      el.clientHeight || el.offsetHeight || el.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    this.fixedTextHeight = elHeight + 5;
    console.log('Height: ' + this.fixedTextHeight);

    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

 onValueChange(evt) {
    this.modifiedText = this.myText + ' ' + evt.target.value;
 }
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-editor {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.custom-editor span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  color:gray
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hizr2d?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: The old text must not be editable!

Comment: @LucianDex check the demo

Comment: @AdritaSharma as per your demo, the new text starts from the below line, it should start right after the existing value.